# The following factories are invalid, FactoryGirl name of model

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have this model

```
   FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :upload, class: Upload do
        before :create do |upload|
         create(:user_2) 
        end
      end
    end
```

The factory of user:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name            "John"
    password              "1234567890"
    factory :user_2 do
      initialize_with {
          User.where(id: 2).first_or_create(
            id: 2,
            first_name:            "John",
            password:              "1234567890",
          )
      }
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the error:

```
/home/developer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/factory_girl-4.4.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:73:in `lint': The following factories are invalid: (FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError)  *upload
```

I don't know what happened with this error

(Update)
I resolve it, i create the Upload object directly when i need it:

```
@upload = Upload.create(fund_source: @fund_source, user: build(:user), status: 'uploaded',  
file: fixture_file_upload('files/HennesseeHedgeFundIndices_UnitTest.xlsx', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'))
```

Comment: 1.check if your factory works without `before(:create)` block 2. what is `user_2` factory? it seems it should depend on `upload`

Comment: May be ````upload```` is a reserved word ?

Comment: Try removing the `|upload|` block, no reason to have it there if you will not be using it.